# Jquery AJAX call to pylons failing intermittently on identical requests

Tags: ajax, jquery, pylons

I am creating an ajax call like so:

```
  var form = $("#form");
  $.ajax({url: "/url/create_web_registration?invite_token=abc",
          data: form.serialize(),
          type: "POST",
          dataType: "json",
          success: $.web_registration.index.registerSubmitSuccess,
          error: $.web_registration.index.registerSubmitError,
  });
```

However when I repeat the request with identical parameters, I sometimes get the success callback and sometimes get the error callback. When the error callback is called, the jqXHR.status is always 0 on a failure, but there is nothing descriptive in statusText, responseText, textStatus or errorThrown.

I did a tcpdump on the HTTP requests and the request looks like:

```
POST /shopkick/v1/user/create_web_registration?invite_token=abc HTTP/1.1
Host: [redacted]:5000
Connection: keep-alive
Referer: http://[redacted]:5000/wr2/abc?invite_token=&zip_code=94123&phone_number=%2B16785556982&facebook-form=
Content-Length: 169
Origin: http://[redacted]:5000
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_7) AppleWebKit/535.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/13.0.782.215 Safari/535.1
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3

invite_token=&zip_code=94123&phone_number=%2B16785552982
```

The response looks like:

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Server: PasteWSGIServer/0.5 Python/2.6.1
Date: Wed, 31 Aug 2011 05:34:10 GMT
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-type: text/plain
Content-Length: 74

{"error_message": "Facebook account already registered", "success": false}
```

I am at a loss to why it is sometimes succeeding and sometimes failing.

Comment: Doesn't *`Facebook account already registered`* give you some hints?

Comment: "Facebook account already registered" is the response from my server code. JQuery doesn't understand the JSON object I'm passing back from the server. As long as it is a HTTP 200 it should be calling the success handler passing the JSON object as the data parameter. And it in fact does call the success handler sometimes with that exact same HTTP response.

Comment: why does in the response you set `Content-type: text/plain` and still send a JSON in the response body? This doesn't seem right. If you intend to send a JSON response set the correct `Content-Type` header to `application/json`.

Comment: I tried setting the content type to text/json but I still encountered the same issue

Comment: The correct MIME type is `application/json`.

Comment: Using application/json didn't help either.

Comment: Try putting the `false` value into double quotes in your JSON response object: `"success": "false"`.

Comment: I tried putting false in quotes and also just tried returning an empty json object i.e. {}, but neither worked

Answer (score 0):

The problem was I was using ajax to submit a form. When I clicked the submit button it would work fine, but when I hit enter in a text input field it would encounter the errors. Apparently hitting enter in a input field was causing the form to submit twice. The fix was to set onsubmit="return false;" for the form to prevent double submission.